# master branch not deleted properly

Tags: git

I am trying to rename my `master` branch to `development`:

```
git checkout -b development master
git push -u origin development
git branch -d master
git push --delete origin master
git remote prune origin
```

It works fine. However, if I try to clone my repository, I will land on an empty folder and I need to do `git checkout development`.

How do I set `development` to be my default branch when I clone?

Comment: I think you will have to go to the remote and check out the branch you want as the default branch.

Comment: `git branch -m master development`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to [Schleis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58456766/1256452), when you run `git clone` with `-b <branchname>` you are telling your Git what to do in its last step.  Remember that `git clone url dest` is effectively shorthand for this six-step command sequence:

1. `mkdir dest`, to create a new empty directory.  If you omit the *`dest`* argument, Git will construct one based on the *`url`* you supply.  (If you name an existing directory, it must be empty.)  The remaining operations will run in this directory as if via `cd dest`, although this does not affect your shell.
2. `git init`: this creates a new, empty repository—the `.git` directory—in the otherwise-empty directory.
3. `git remote add origin url`: this adds a remote, named `origin`, to the configuration of this new empty repository.  (You can choose a name other than `origin` if you like, via the `-o` option to `git clone`.)  If you used `--single-branch`, the single branch is effectively passed through at this point.  (I say "effectively" only because this part of the process is built in to the `git clone` command itself.)
4. Set up any additional `git config` commands you specify in the `git clone` command (with `-c` options added after the word `clone`: `-c` options *before* the word `clone` may apply to the cloning process, but are not set *in* the clone).
5. Run `git fetch origin` (or whatever remote name you chose).  This obtains whatever commits are published at the URL.  It also gets a list of branch and tag names (and other references) from the other Git; those branch names become your *remote-tracking* names, and those tag names are generally copied to your repository as well, at this point.<sup>1</sup>
6. Finally, your Git picks some branch name to, in effect, pass to `git checkout`.  Which branch name is your Git going to `git checkout`?  The answer depends on whether you provide a `-b` flag.

If you provide `-b foo`, your Git will try to `git checkout foo`.  This depends on the existence of `origin/foo`, created in step 5 from *their* Git's `foo`.  If you provide `-b master`, your Git will try to `git checkout master`.  But if you *don't* provide *any* `-b`, your Git asks *their* Git which branch *they* recommend.

What's happening in this case is that their Git is recommending `master`, or not recommending anything.  We can't tell which of these is the case from what you've posted—but it doesn't matter, because they *don't have a `master`*.  If they recommend that your Git use their `master` to make your `master`, this will fail: they don't have a `master`.  If they make no recommendation at all, your Git will assume, as a last ditch thing, that it should use `master`, and will look for your `origin/master` as copied from their `master`, but you won't have it.

So, no matter what happens at this point, your Git has no branch to check out.  You *do* have `origin/development`, though, as copied from their `development`.  So you can run `git checkout development`, which looks around, sees that you don't have a `development`, looks around some more, sees that you *do* have `origin/development`, and does what you wanted.

> How do I set development to be my default branch when I clone?

You can try to get *their* Git to recommend that name.

To do that in a traditional (non-GitHub-ish) way, you log in to the server, navigate to the `--bare` repository (wherever it is), and run:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/development
```

and now their Git will recommend `development`.

To do that with GitHub, see [GitHub's instructions](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-the-default-branch).  To do that with some other web hosting service, see *their* instructions, wherever they may be.

---

<sup>1</sup>A branch or tag name can only exist if the object ID recorded in that branch or tag name exists too.  Hence, if you limited the set of commits that get copied, your Git may have to omit some names.  For instance, if one of their tags, such as `v0.1`, points to a commit that you deliberately omitted via `--single-branch` and/or `--shallow`, you can't have that tag.  If their branch `debug` points to some commit that you didn't take because you said `--single-branch foo`, you can't have `origin/debug`.  Note that `--shallow` implies `--single-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

By default git will want to use `master` and most repos would be using this branch as the "stable".  So in general you would want to have this behavior.

However in your git clone command there is an option `-b <branchname>` that will checkout a particular branch or just clone the named branch.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

So in your case, you would want to change your clone command to `git clone -b development <repo>`